# Asp.net writing server side file

Tags: asp.net

Needed to write a server text file as the output of a business process initiated by ASP.net app.
The text file writing code is in a library file using standard stream code

All worked OK in IDE.

Publish and it falls over trying to write file. IIS is reluctant to write to the file system.

Much rummaging around and hair pulling finally led to a solution. It is not pretty and only applicable in a situation where you have control over the Webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw your answer.

It doesn't need to be inside your *inetpub* or *wwwroot* directory for that matter, it could be anywhere, as long as security permissions are set correctly for the user under which the application is running as.

But this is actually desired. If not just imagine the consequences of allowing write access anywhere.

Also, there's no need for the virtual directory. You could create a directory like C:\ProcessOutput, and grant permissions accordingly and it should work just fine.
Another option, would be to have a service account created, and impersonate as that user within your application only for when you need to write that output file.

Comment: Hi Pablo, Thanks for your response. Understand the conceptual necessities. What I put up was just a way of getting a result. Not pretty but when you are not well versed in the security and you are dealing with an internal application then it does the job. Sort of figured the virtual directory mightn't be necessary but ran out of time to experiment further.

Comment: Yup, perfectly understandable, been there too :) 
I Just wanted to make sure you didn't think it was mandatory to have a Virtual Directory for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:
Create a physical directory on the webserver with the physical path of:
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebapp\myOutputFileDirectory

Make a virtual directory that points at the directory.

Using windows explorer give write permission to the physical directory to IIS_IUSRS.

Use a physical path of c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebapp\myOutputFileDirectory in your Streamwriter code

Maybe the virtual path could point to somewhere more sensible across the LAN if you get the security sorted but I am sufficiently battered to accept this small crumb with gratitude.